# Ошибка при запуске Telegram бота на Webhook

Tags: api, flask, telegram, бот

Запрос `https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/getWebhookInfo`
дает результат вида:

{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://fastcolor.site:443","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":16,"last_error_date":1568135087,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 500 Internal Server Error","max_connections":40}}

Хотя сайт подписан SSL сертификтом, выданным регистратором, поэтому самоподписанных сертификатов не создавал. Сам код бота такой:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import telebot, time
import os

application = Flask(__name__)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('<TOKEN>')
bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(2)
bot.set_webhook(url="https://site.site:443")

@application.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
  r = request.get_json()
  if "message" in r.keys():
    chat_id = r["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    if "text" in r["message"]:
      text_mess = r["message"]["text"]
    else:
      bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Какая то не понятная проблема", parse_mode='HTML')
      return "ok", 200
  if text_mess == '/start':
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Привет WebHook")
    return "ok", 200

if __name__ == "main":
  application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', '443')), ssl_context=('cert.crt', 'cert.key'))
```

В чем может быть проблема? Указан порт для доступа по SSL сервера 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил структуру тела кода таким образом и всё заработало:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


@application.route("/<TOKEN>", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200

@application.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url="https://www.site.site/<TOKEN>")
    return "!", 200

@application.route("/registration")
def registration():
    return render_template('registration.html')
```